# cmake msys2 mingw is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: windows, gcc, cmake, mingw-w64, msys2

Yesterday i was able to configure and compile my project without any issues. Now i did some system updates and the compiler isn't able to pass the check. I'm stuck there for hours now-

I'm running windows 10 with the current MSYS2 installed. Packages are up to date. When i check with --debug-trycompile i see the testCCompiler.c file is created and there is also an executable which i can run without any problems. Therefore i have no clue what exactly is causing this error.

When i go to the directory and execute the exact same command, it is working too.

```
[cmake] Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
[cmake] Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
[cmake] CMake Error at C:/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
[cmake]   The C compiler
[cmake] 
[cmake]     "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"
[cmake] 
[cmake]   is not able to compile a simple test program.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   It fails with the following output:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     Change Dir: C:/Users/bscb/Documents/code/MachineLearning/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
[cmake]     
[cmake]     Run Build Command(s):C:/Ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_aef7d && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_aef7d.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
[cmake]     [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_aef7d.exe
[cmake]     FAILED: cmTC_aef7d.exe 
[cmake]     cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe    CMakeFiles/cmTC_aef7d.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj  -o cmTC_aef7d.exe -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
[cmake]     Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
[cmake]     ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution was that there was an init script for cmd.exe created by conda which linked to a non existing batch file.

Comment: Hi bazz-dee, could you give some more information on this solution?